# How do I link 2 css files in 1 wygwam entry? is that possible?

Tags: ee2, pixelandtonic

I'm using wygwam as a page building field and have a webpage built on dreamweaver attached to 2 css which are the main css and overlay tab panel css. I saw Wygwam Template links from p&t which I was thinking of linking 2 css template, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Wygwam, but you can always use the @import option in CSS to internally link another CSS file within the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe create a custom style set per the P&T docs: 
https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/using/style_set.html